# Extracting arguments from dynamic URLs

Tags: uri, views

I am new to Drupal 7 and am trying to do the following:

1) I have a node that's aliased to domain.com/inventory - the node has code that'll generate dynamic content.

2) My site creates dynamic URLs like domain.com/inventory/ABCD and I need to know how to a) figure out that I'm on the /inventory page and b) extract the argument "ABCD" from the URL.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

If your node is 12, your internal path is node/12 when the alias is 'inventory'. In that case arg(0) gives you 'node' and arg(1) gives you '12'.

In the case of dynamic URLs like inventory/ABCD, I assume that the internal path is 'inventory/ABCD' (so that inventory/ABCD does not have anything to do with node 12). Then arg(0) gives you 'inventory' and arg(1) gives you 'ABCD'.

Comment: arg(0) and arg(1) actually gives me 'node' and '12'.  I was able to get the path using drupal_get_path_alias();

Comment: I couldn't give a concret answer without knowing the mechanism of your menu system and what is your "real" path. Try to look at $_GET['q'] or arg(2) (if available). I think your site uses hook_menu to add aliases like inventory/ABCD to node/12/ABCD, so your real (internal) path is node/12/ABCD and arg(2) = 'ABCD'.

Comment: I was able to get node/12/ABCD and arg(2) = 'ABCD' to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is [drupal_get_path_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias).

```
$current_path = drupal_get_path_alias();
```

You can then explode that path on '/' to get your argument.

Comment: My problem is that I can't get a node (/inventory) to also display (/inventory/ABCD), so I can't get to a point to extract the variables.

Comment: Well in that case you can try using that path alias > patterns and see if there are any tokens that could be use for populating that variable. If not i would make a hook menu in a custom module but their might be a better way..

Comment: Got node/12/ABCD and arg(2) = 'ABCD' to work for now.  I think I'll just live without the alias.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are pretty good, also look at `drupal_lookup_path()` and `request_uri()` for related functions around what you're trying to do.

Comment: If my node is /inventory, how do I even get Drupal to display /inventory/ABCD, which is technically not a real node, but a node /inventory, with an argument 'ABCD'

Comment: actually, your node is *always* using the system path "node/XXX" where XXX is the node ID, and if you're displaying your node at "inventory/YYY" then you're using an alias "inventory/YYY", not an alias "inventory" with an argument "YYY". `arg()` will always return the system path, but `request_uri()` will return the current url (excluding the domain) as a string even if it is an alias. It shouldn't be too hard to parse that string to get out the "argument" if that's really the way you want to do things here.

Comment: Thanks.  I got node/12/ABCD and arg(2) = 'ABCD' to work for now.

Comment: why not just do something like `$url = request_uri(); $url = ltrim( $url, '/' ); $url_array = explode('/', $url);`?